# undefined reference to '_gfortran_transpose_r8' when linking with ATLAS math library

Tags: fortran, gfortran, rhel6, atlas

I'm currently using `devtoolset-7` on RHEL (gcc 7.2.1) and linking a gfortran project with the ATLAS math library:

```
gfortran -o $EXE $OBJ libgamess-xmvb.a -L/usr/lib64/atlas -llf77blas -latlas
```

The static library `/usr/lib64/atlas` was provided for the build and configured to use ATLAS, however linking produces the following errors:

```
/usr/local/src/gamess/libgamess-xmvb.a(int.o): In function `__preint_MOD_int_gijklsh':
int.F90:(.text+0x2e41e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transpose_r8'
/usr/local/src/gamess/libgamess-xmvb.a(bio.o): In function `tensortran_cas_':
bio.F90:(.text+0x142a61): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transpose_r8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

We do not have source for `int.o`, `bio.o`.  I am trying to determine if we missed linking additional libraries from ATLAS to resolve the errors with `_gfortran_transpose_r8` above?

Comment: do you have any source/link files to post for clarity?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] we need the exact description how to reproduce your steps. Namely, you have to tell use **how** are you linking your code. Which commands do you use. Also, the *complete* output may be important or even ncecessary. Do not just select one line, cut and paste a larger relevant part of the output.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  Included additional info above.

Comment: are the static and shared library atlas the same ?

Comment: What version of gfortran was used to compile `int.o` and `bio.o`? You cannot mix and match Fortran compilers (even the same compiler across revisions) because there is no compiler-agnostic binary interface. Also, gfortran ships with a specific libgfortran that changes from one version of gfortran to the next.

Comment: In line with the comments above, gamess and possibly liblf77blas (is that part of atlas?) as well as atlas and your program would require all building by the same major version of gfortran.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tips regarding libgfortran versions.  I will rebuild accordingly.